# Cursor Adapter with ImageView

Tags: android

What I've got is a cursor adapter for a list view. Within this adapter we have the below code. The item is a ImageView and i'm trying to make it visible and set it to the image name that is in the value coming from the database. AS you can see from my logcat when it is null and when it is populated it still fails.  I'm assuming i need to convert the string to a bitmap object or a drawable. Anyone?

Log cat:

```
06-21 09:32:38.020: I/PROJECTCARUSO(10061): is_stamp: observation_4
06-21 09:32:38.020: I/PROJECTCARUSO(10061): is_stamp2: observation_4
06-21 09:32:38.020: I/System.out(10061): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: observation_4
06-21 09:32:38.101: I/PROJECTCARUSO(10061): is_stamp: null
06-21 09:32:38.101: I/PROJECTCARUSO(10061): is_stamp3: null
06-21 09:32:38.101: I/System.out(10061): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 





if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS)) {
             String is_stamp = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "is_stamp0: " + is_stamp);
             if (is_stamp != null) {
                 if (is_stamp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                     Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "is_stamp1: " + is_stamp);
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "is_stamp2: " + is_stamp);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
             } else {
                 Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "is_stamp3: " + is_stamp);
                 view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }
```

Comment: Where do you set the image in your code?

Comment: Originally it is set to a default img, and i'm trying to change that here

Comment: I was asking exactly what code you used to set the image, `imageView.set....`.

Comment: see my answer i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drawable is_stamp_draw = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + is_stamp, null, getActivity().getPackageName())); 
view.setBackground(is_stamp_draw);
```